# Android адаптивный контраст изображения при помощи openCV

Tags: android, c++, изображения, opencv

Задача - реализовать адаптивное увеличение контраста, как на изображении слева:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что при обычном преобразовании изображения в ч/б и увеличении контрастности я получаю такой результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ищу описание или реализацию алгоритма на с++ при помощи инструментов openCV для использования в Android приложении.

Comment: То, что вы такой результат получаете, то это норма, просто контраст увеличивается для всей картинки одинаково, поэтому более тёмная область получатся настолько тёмной. Скорее всего тут были использованы какие-то сложные фильтры, а потом уже был увеличен контраст

Comment: Можете тут почитать про фильтры изображения http://habrahabr.ru/post/142818/

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, спасибо, но нет. тут используются другие алгоритмы обработки. Компании ABBYY, например, известен этот алгоритм http://habrahabr.ru/company/abbyy/blog/218285/

Comment: Искал решение для вас, а нашёл доки от Oracle, чтобы наоборот можно было бы делать тени, как Material Design))

Comment: Посмотрите тут, может какой вам подойдёт http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/

Comment: К примеру этот http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/ThresholdFilter.html

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, опять же, спасибо, но это не то. во-первых, этот фильтр даст аналогичный результат моему, судя по его описанию. во-вторых, я ищу реализацию для Android NDK, поскольку обработка изображения на Java займет гораздо больше времени.

Comment: Мне кажется, что данные фильтры также работаю с использованием NDK, если нет, то процесс будет не намного дольше, вы точно разницы не заметите. Что на счёт такого же результата, то я бы поспорил, там явно видно, что цвета разные, но результат нужный. Во всяком случае попробуйте

Comment: @GrafOrlov , может быть окажется полезен алгоритм адаптивной бинаризации [Кристиана Вольфа](http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/software/binarize/). Исходники на С++ / OpenCV.

Comment: @alexis031182, спасибо, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось гораздо проще, чем я мог предположить.
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.